# Filling a DataFrame with "sign" numbers

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame full of floats (positive and negative) and some NaN.
I'd like to replace every single float number with its sign:

- if it's NaN -> it remains Nan
- if positive -> replace with 1
- if negative -> replace with -1
- if zero -> leave it as 0

Any suggestions to make this massive replacement?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[-1,3,0,5],
                   'B':[4,5,6,5],
                   'C':[8,-9,np.nan,7]})

print (df)
   A  B    C
0 -1  4  8.0
1  3  5 -9.0
2  0  6  NaN
3  5  5  7.0
```

```
print (df > 0)
       A     B      C
0  False  True   True
1   True  True  False
2  False  True  False
3   True  True   True

print (df < 0)
       A      B      C
0   True  False  False
1  False  False   True
2  False  False  False
3  False  False  False

df[df > 0] = 1
df[df < 0] = -1

print (df)
   A  B    C
0 -1  1  1.0
1  1  1 -1.0
2  0  1  NaN
3  1  1  1.0
```

Comment: How does this method work when there is another column having a different datatype such as `float`?

Comment: I think  OP says there are float and NaN. So I think there are only numeric values.

Comment: You're right, but is there any way that this method would work in a generic case?

Comment: More general solution: `df1 = df.fillna(1).apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
df1[df1 > 0] = 1
df1[df1 < 0] = -1
print (df1.fillna(df))
`

Comment: @VedangMehta you can slice for column ranges or apply an operation only to a single column.

Answer (score 47):

You can use [`np.sign`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sign.html):

```
df
Out[100]: 
     A
0 -4.0
1  2.0
2  NaN
3  0.0

import numpy as np
np.sign(df["A"])

Out[101]: 
0   -1.0
1    1.0
2    NaN
3    0.0
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

In order to apply to all columns, you can directly pass the dataframe:

```
df
Out[121]: 
          0         1         2         3
0 -2.932447 -1.686652       NaN -0.908441
1  1.254436  0.000000  0.072242  0.796944
2  2.626737  0.169639 -1.457195  1.169238
3  0.000000 -1.174251  0.660111  1.115518
4 -1.998091 -0.125095  0.000000 -0.506782

np.sign(df)
Out[122]: 
     0    1    2    3
0 -1.0 -1.0  NaN -1.0
1  1.0  0.0  1.0  1.0
2  1.0  1.0 -1.0  1.0
3  0.0 -1.0  1.0  1.0
4 -1.0 -1.0  0.0 -1.0
```

Comment: Is there a way to resolve the Pandas warning this gives? `A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead` Rather annoying that this pops up and I need to write extra code to temporarily hide warnings. Else, I have to write additional code like `df['sign_A'] = -1; df.loc[np.sign(df['A'])==1, 'sign_A'] = 1; df.loc[np.sign(df['A'])==0, 'sign_A'] = 0` I just dislike how this requires extra code to dismiss the warning...Any resolutions would be appreciated

Comment: current documentation: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sign.html

Answer (score 4):

Code -

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'x' : [-5.3, 2.5, 0, float('nan')]})

df['x'] = df['x'].apply(func = lambda x : x if not x else x // abs(x))

print(df)
```

Output -

```
    x
0  -1
1   1
2   0
3 NaN
```

Comment: why do you create lambda function? `.apply(modify)` would work just fine