# Pandas convert positive number to 1 and negative number to -1

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column of positive and negative number. How to convert this column to a new column to realize convert positive number to 1 and negative number to -1?

Comment: What happen if `0` ?

Comment: np.sign() will work.

Comment: Answered at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37377478/filling-a-dataframe-with-sign-numbers

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need [`numpy.sign`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sign.html)

```
df['new'] = np.sign(df['col'])
```

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'col':[-1,3,-5,7,1,0]})
df['new'] = np.sign(df['col'])
print (df)

   col  new
0   -1   -1
1    3    1
2   -5   -1
3    7    1
4    1    1
5    0    0
```

Answer (score 4):

It's really easy to perform this task by -

For whole data frame -

```
df[df < 0] = -1
df[df > 0] = 1
```

For specific column -

```
df['column_name'][df['column_name'] < 0] = -1
df['column_name'][df['column_name'] > 0] = 1
```

Comment: Double-indexing like that could cause a `SettingWithCopyWarning`, couldn't it? It seems like it'd be better to use `.loc`, like `df.loc[df['column_name'] < 0, 'column_name'] = -1`

Answer (score 3):

```
df[df < 0] = -1
df[df > 0] = 1
```

no behaviour defined for `df == 0`